# Is there a way to negate an Option<bool>?

Tags: rust

I'm facing a provided function that takes an `Into<Option<bool>>` as a parameter but I want to pass it the opposite value of my current bool.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried `opt.map(|b| !b)`?

Comment: I was going to do match v.as_bool() {
                    Some(b) => Some(!b),
                    None => None,
                } but seems that map works!

Comment: That's basically what `map` does internally.

Comment: You can also do `opt.map(Not::not)`. It's a matter of preference though.